# How to receive a BYTE[] from C#

Tags: c#, byte

There are two questions:

1. I try to make a program which will need to use an COM component(OCX) created by MFC.
   Assume the component name is MyOCX. MyOCX has a function as "ReadUserData (BYTE* Buf)".(I can see this function spec has become to ReadUserData(ref byte Buf) in C#.) The Buf actually is BYTE[30]. The content is a string: 100.

Here is partial of my code:

```
        byte buf = new byte();
        if (MyOCX.ReadUserData(ref buf))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                MyOCX.ReadUserData(ref buf);
                textBox3.Text += (char)buf;
            }
        }
```

There is no any error during running, but the textBox3.Text content will be "111111111111111111111111111111", I think this is because I always get "100" the first letter '1' for 30 times.

I would like to ask how to write this code to make I can get "100" from original BYTE[30];

2. Another question is not only has ReadUserData(BYTE* Buf), but also has WriteUserData(BYTE* Buf). I would like to write "200" back into Buf. Please tell me how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how MyOXC.ReadUserData works, try this:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[30];

if (MyOCX.ReadUserData(ref buf))
    for (int i = 0; i < byte.Length; i++)
       textBox3.Text += (char)buf[i];
```

In your code it looks like the first read succeeds, and, because you only supplied a single byte to write data to only returned the first character the '1'. The subsequent calls probably fail, which is why buf is never changed, so you keep on printing out the original value.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

After use the approach you told, it cannot be compiled. The reason is 
1. ReadUserData(ref buf) has a invalid parameter.
2. Parameter 1: "ref byte []" cannot be translated to "ref byte".

Comment: try removing the ref

Comment: Thanks for your help. unfortunately, it cannot be compiled. It shows "byte []" cannot be translated to "ref byte".